# why is there no metadata on sources in mapbox style spec?

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

In a Mapbox style object, the root and each layer have `metadata` attributes, but source elements does not. This could really help third-party applications IMHO, is there a specific reason why there is no metadata at the source level?

Comment: I have no idea. But you're right, Mapbox-GL-JS does reject styles with a `metadata` attribute on a source. What's your use case?

Comment: Use case is adding some extra information at the source level, such as an Identify endpoint for ArcGIS REST services that are accessed as XYZ

Comment: But who would read the metadata tag and do something with it?

Comment: We are building an SDK based on the mapbox style format. It allows switching between openlayers and mapbox-gl-js, so the SDK would read it

Comment: Something else I found is that it does work on the initial style, but not when the style is updated with setStyle, then it raises errors. So it seems validation is not performed on the style from the constructor?